# SMTP error with sending Emails on moodle 3.0

Tags: php, email, smtp, moodle, smtpclient

I have the same Email configuration (in messages output) for 2 Moodle installation on the same server:

1. version 2.9.1+
2. version 3.0

I am using Exchange server as SMTP host server.

On the 2.9 the emails are working fine but on the 3.0 I am having an error:

```
    250-SIZE 37748736
                                  250-PIPELINING
                                  250-DSN
                                  250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                                  250-STARTTLS
                                  250-X-ANONYMOUSTLS
                                  250-AUTH NTLM LOGIN
                                  250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM
                                  250-8BITMIME
                                  250-BINARYMIME
                                  250-CHUNKING
                                  250 XRDST
 2015-12-22 09:47:25    CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
 2015-12-22 09:47:25    SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
 2015-12-22 09:47:25    SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "220 2.0.0 SMTP server     ready                         
 2015-12-22 09:47:25    SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
 2015-12-22 09:47:26    SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
 2015-12-22 09:47:26    CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
 2015-12-22 09:47:26    SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
 2015-12-22 09:47:26    SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  ""
 2015-12-22 09:47:26    SERVER -> CLIENT:
 2015-12-22 09:47:26    SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed:
 2015-12-22 09:47:26    Connection: closed
 2015-12-22 09:47:26    SMTP connect() failed.     https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Note that I am using the exact same configuration except that in 2.9 you don't have the option to choose between (LOGIN, PLAIN, NTLM) but it is exists in 3.0 and I have tried them all.

Does anybody has a clue what is going on? is it a bug or ma I missing anything, it has been 2 days and it is becoming frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is an old discussion, for community reference the issue has been tracked in MDL-52637 and fixed in v3.0.3.
Details at https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-52637.

HTH,
Matteo

Answer (score -1):

If you have a troubles with Moodle SMTP outgoing mails and its not working, you can do several things to check it.

**Check SMTP configuration**

at `/admin/settings.php?section=outgoingmailconfig`.

1. Set `smtpuser` address similar to `noreplyaddress`
2. Make sure connection port is follows to `smtpsecure`. For example `SSL` port is `465` and `smtphosts` has to be like `mysmtp.server.com:465`

**Test email send with build-in Moodle tool**

at `/admin/testoutgoingmailconf.php`

1. Update current user (seems you are admin) email at `/user/editadvanced.php?id=2&course=1` to `smtpuser` value
2. Set debug mode at `/admin/settings.php?section=debugging`:

- `debug` as developer mode
- `debugdisplay` - yes

3. Test and look at results

**Manual test with own PHP script (if still not working)**

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
$mail = get_mailer();
$mail->Sender = 'mysmtpaddress@site.com';//from your settings
$mail->Host = "smtp.host";//from your settings
$mail->Port = 465;//from your settings
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';//from your settings
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->setFrom("mysmtpaddress@site.com", "TEST");//from your settings
$mail->Username = "mysmtpaddress@site.com";//from your settings
$mail->Password = "MY_PASSWORD";//from your settings
$mail->AuthType = "Login";
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "Email Subject Line";
$mail->Body = "This is a new text body.";
$mail->addAddress('yourmailtotestmoodlesmtp@site.com');//your receive email
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$send = $mail->send();
echo print_r($send, 1);
```

Comment: The data provided by the OP clearly shows they are using STARTTLS not SSMTP, and the there is a bug in the client

Comment: I think this answer can help for people who facing problems like this, i don't think you have to downvote my extended answer, but it's up to you.